# AngularJS + RequireJS Startover

Tags: angularjs, module, requirejs

I'm a noob on AngularJS and I want to start an application with Angular and RequireJS.
I've read lots of thing about it but not exactly what i'm searching for.

I started an application with Yeoman and generator-angular-require.
The problem is I want to organise my app like this :

```
app
|__ scripts
    |__ controllers
        |__ index.controller.js
        |__ user.controller.js
        |__ include.js
        |__ ...
    |__ directives
    |__ services
    |__ templates
        |__ index.template.html
        |__ user.template.html 
        |__ ...
    |__ init.js
    |__ app.js
```

**Init.js** (Require Config)

```
require.config
({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: 
    {
        'angular' : '../bower_components/angular/angular.min',
        'angular-route' : '../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min',
        'angular-cookies' : '../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min',
        'angular-sanitize' : '../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min',
        'angular-resource' : '../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min',
        'angular-animate' : '../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min',
        'angular-touch' : '../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min',

        'foundation' : '../bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min',
        'angular-foundation' : '../bower_components/angular-foundation/mm-foundation.min'
    },
    shim:
    {
        'angular' : 
        {
            'exports' : 'angular'
        },
        'angular-route': 
        [
            'angular'
        ],
        'angular-cookies': 
        [
            'angular'
        ],
        'angular-sanitize': 
        [
            'angular'
        ],
        'angular-resource': 
        [
            'angular'
        ],
        'angular-animate': 
        [
            'angular'
        ],
        'angular-touch': 
        [
            'angular'
        ],
        'angular-mocks':
        {
            deps:['angular'],
            'exports':'angular.mock'
        }
    },
    priority: 
    [
        'angular'
    ]
});

window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';

require(['app'], function(app)
{
    'use strict';

    app.init();
});
```

**app.js**

```
define(function(require)
{
    'use strict';

    var angular = require('angular');
    var services = require('./services/include');
    var controllers = require('./controllers/include');
    var directives = require('./directives/include');

    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['services', 'controllers', 'directives']);

    app.init = function()
    {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
    };

    app.config
    ([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider)
        {
            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', { templateUrl: 'templates/index.template', controller: 'IndexCtrl' })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }
    ]);

    app.run(function($window)
    {

    });

    return app;
});
```

This seams to be ok. But, I don't know how to define my Controllers and what to put in my `controllers/include.js` file.

I've tried lots of things like defining a module and put all controllers in it, but nothing works.

**controllers/include.js**

```
define
([
    'angular',

    'controllers/index.controller',
    'controllers/user.controller'
], function(angular)
{
    return angular.module('MyApp.Controllers', []);
});
```

**controllers/index.controller.js**

```
define(['angular'], function(angular)
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module('MyApp.Controllers').controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope)
    {

    });
});
```

Everytime I try something new, I've got the same error :

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp

I now it's something about a module which doesn't exists. I'm pretty sure it's about my `MyApp.Controllers` module. But I don't know what to do for my code to be correct.

Does someone have an idea ? I'm really lost with that 2 files. I don't know how I can define all my controllers in separate files and include them in one file.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.

I had to change lots of things but with the help of https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed, I'm now able to organize my solution as I wanted.